# How to find average in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi i am trying to create a programm in vb.net to find a average of number using only one variable   for value with inputbox and second for count number should be negative but i can't get accurate answere 
here is the code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim num, count As Integer
    num = InputBox("Please enter number") 'for first entry
    While num > 0    ' here we have to check it that the num is not negative then to start
        num = InputBox("Please enter number")
        num += num
        count += 1             'this will calculate how many times number added    
    End While
    MsgBox("Average is " & num / count)


End Sub
```

Comment: Could you use a `list (of integer)` instead of an `integer`, to hold the values given by the user. You could then hold the total of the values given by the user in the list as well. Giving you only 2 variables. I could put together some sample code, however I am not familiar with the `inputbox` form tool and sure why you need num>0.

Answer (score 2):

use this code... i am still need temp variable because before exit the loop, the value should not in

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim num, count As Integer
    count = 0
    num = 0
    While num >= 0    ' here we have to check it that the num is not negative then to start
        Dim temp As Integer
        temp = InputBox("Please enter number")
        If temp < 0 Then
            Exit While
        End If
        count += 1             'this will calculate how many times number added 
        num += temp
    End While
    MsgBox("Average is " & (num / count))
End Sub
```

Comment: Remember to test to make sure the number is actually a number and not a string. Eg via: `Integer.TryParse` etc

Comment: glad to help you Syed, my code is not optimized... the loop (while) should not check the num (>=0) since we exit use temp LOL ... 

Stuart , ty for the code!, i am just thinking to input as string and then convert it (use Val() ) ...

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)        Handles Button1.Click
Dim num, count, avg As Integer
num = InputBox("Please enter number") 'for first entry
While num > 0    ' here we have to check it that the num is not negative then to start
    avg += num
    count += 1             'this will calculate how many times number added    
    num = InputBox("Please enter number")
End While
    MsgBox("Average is " & avg / count)
End Sub
```